# Mocking a Groovy Service with Spring Boot

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, groovy, spring-boot

I am testing a Spring Boot application that I am writing in Groovy, and I want to mock out one of the @Components.

Were I using plain Java, I would just mock it out with Mockito in a test @Configuration, but that doesn't work with groovy in versions <2.0 (see https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/72 ) and in versions > 2.0, it breaks with Spring (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6520). Now I'm looking for a workaround--other libraries, a different test design, all are fine.

Here is a standalone example that illustrates what I'm going for (see comment in test):

```
package testing

import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner


@SpringBootApplication
public class TheguildRegisterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(tech.theguild.TheguildRegisterApplication.class, args);
    }
}

class Account {
    String firstName
    String lastName
}

@Component
class AccountService {

    List<Account> getAllAccounts() {
        return [
                new Account(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"),
                new Account(firstName: "Sally", lastName: "Smith")
        ]
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class MockTesting {

    @Autowired AccountService accountService

    @Test void test1() {

        // Create Mock Data
        List<Account> accounts = [
                [firstName: "The Cat", lastName: "In The Hat"]
        ].collect {d -> d as Account}

        //
        // Replace the data in AccountService here with a mock
        //

        Assert.assertEquals(accountService.getAllAccounts().size(), 1)

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unclear what it is you're trying to mock here and for what purpose. I think you may have oversimplified a bit. Have you applied the standard advice of using constructor injection instead of field injection and thus perhaps avoiding the need for a context test in the first place?

Comment: You're right, I did oversimplify a bit. In reality, there is a service behind a REST API, and I'm trying to mock out a call to the database with hard-coded data for integration testing the REST API. The real configuration is comparatively complex with several services talking to one another, etc, but there is only one place that calls the database, so I'd like to integration test everything except the call to the database. Essentially, I just want to replace one service in the stack with a mocked service that I can configure per test, while keeping the rest the same.

Comment: Very strange. I have had absolutely no trouble using Mockito mocks as Spring beans with Mockito 1.9.7. I just dropped a `mock(Foo)` in an `@Bean` and autowired the bean into the test to use as a normal mock.

Comment: Were you using Groovy? It works for me in Java, but not groovy. I'll try 1.9.7 in particular, maybe it's a version issue...

Comment: Yep, with 1.10.19 I get `java.lang.NullPointerException...at testing.MockTesting.test1(MockTesting.groovy:75)` (i.e. this issue, https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/72)  and with 1.9.7, I get  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.getMockSettings(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;
 at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:109)` which is essentially the same as https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6520 .

Comment: For posterity, `@Configuration
@Profile("test")
class MockTestConfig {

    @Primary @Bean
    AccountService getService() {
        return mock(AccountService)
    }

}` That looks ugly but hopefully communicates the configuration :)

Comment: Ah, somehow Spring Boot is trying to handle the mock *itself*. Maybe `@SpringBootTest`, which is newer than what I had available; I was building what they now call configuration slices by hand. The `@Configuration` was a nested class on the test, not something that was scanned.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?